# Changing blocktyle in tikzposter

Tags: block, tikzposter

I am using `tikzposter` and would like to change only one parameter of the  `blockstyle` that I use and was already included in package (i.e. I did not define this `blockstyle` by myself).

> Are there any "one-liners" for doing this, so that I would not have to copy the whole definition of the style before changing the default value of that one parameter?

Just to be concrete: here is the definition of the modified `Default`, where I have changed the value of the parameter `titleinnersep` from `1cm` to `3mm`:

```
 \defineblockstyle{Default}{
    titlewidthscale=1, bodywidthscale=1, titlecenter,
    titleoffsetx=0pt, titleoffsety=0pt, bodyoffsetx=0pt, bodyoffsety=0pt,
    bodyverticalshift=0pt, roundedcorners=30, linewidth=0.4cm,
    titleinnersep=3mm, bodyinnersep=1cm 
 }{
 \begin{scope}[line width=\blocklinewidth, rounded corners=\blockroundedcorners]
    \ifBlockHasTitle %
    \draw[color=blocktitlebgcolor, fill=blocktitlebgcolor] (blockbody.south west) rectangle (blocktitle.north east);
    \draw[color=blocktitlebgcolor, fill=blockbodybgcolor] (blockbody.south west) rectangle (blockbody.north east);
    \else
    \draw[color=blocktitlebgcolor, fill=blockbodybgcolor] (blockbody.south west) rectangle (blockbody.north east);
    \fi
 \end{scope}
}
```

(I could not find any better/more tags, feel free to edit them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the options listed in the manual, you can set the `block` style to default and add key-value parameters in the optional argument to `\useblockstyle`, e.g.

```
\useblockstyle[titleinnersep=3mm]{Default}
```